# C# is crashing on an event

Tags: c#, events, filesystemwatcher

I am trying to create a C# service as a console app.

The main code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        var exitCode = HostFactory.Run(
            x =>
            {
                x.Service<HeartBeat>(s =>
                {
                    s.ConstructUsing(heartbeat => new HeartBeat());
                    s.WhenStarted(heartbeat => heartbeat.Start());
                    s.WhenStopped(heartbeat => heartbeat.Stop());
                });

                x.RunAsLocalSystem();
                x.SetServiceName("UpgradeServices");
                x.SetDisplayName("Service Upgrade");
                x.SetDescription("Service is monitoring new version.");
            });

        int exitCodeValue = (int)Convert.ChangeType(exitCode, exitCode.GetTypeCode());
        Environment.ExitCode = exitCodeValue;
}
```

Then I have code for deleting and copying files as per below:

```
public class MovingFiles
{
    public string fileName;
    public string destPath;
    private DirectoryInfo directory;
    private DirectoryInfo myFile;
    public string sourcePath;
    public string targetPath;

    public MovingFiles(string sourceFolder, string targetFolder)
    {
        sourcePath = sourceFolder;
        targetPath = targetFolder;
    }

    public void deleteFilesMethod()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
        string deleteString;
        //First we want to delete all files except for the JSON file as this has all of the important settings
        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
        {
            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(targetPath);

            // Loop through each files and then delete these if they are not the JSON file
            foreach (string s in files)
            {
                deleteString = targetPath;
                // The file name which is returned will be deleted
                fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);

                if (fileName != "appsettings.json")
                {
                    deleteString = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

                    try
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Delete(deleteString);
                    }
                    catch (System.IO.IOException e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The loop didn't run, source path doesn't exist");
        }
    }

    public void copyFilesMethod()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);

        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
        {
            // Searching for the latest directory created in the sourcePath folder
            directory = new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath);
            myFile = (from f in directory.GetDirectories()
                      orderby f.LastWriteTime descending
                      select f).First();

            sourcePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, myFile.Name);
            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);

            // Copy the files and overwrite destination files if they already exist.
            foreach (string s in files)
            {
                // Use static Path methods to extract only the file name from the path.
                fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);

                if (fileName != "appsettings.json")
                {

                    destPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

                    try
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Copy(s, destPath, true);
                    }
                    catch (System.IO.IOException e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The loop didn't run, source path doesn't exist");
        }

        // Keep console window open in debug mode.
        Console.WriteLine("Procedure has been completed.");
}
```

This should be triggered once there is a new file, which I have written as this:

```
class FileMonitor
{
    public FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    public string sourcePath;
    public string targetPath;

    public FileMonitor(string sourceFolder, string targetFolder)
    {
        sourcePath = sourceFolder;
        targetPath = targetFolder;
    }

    public void watch()
    {
            watcher.Path = sourcePath;
            watcher.NotifyFilter =  NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                                   | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
                                   | NotifyFilters.CreationTime;
            //var one = NotifyFilters.FileName;
            watcher.Filter = "*.*";
            watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler (OnChanged);
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(25000);
    }

    public void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        //Copies file to another directory.
        MovingFiles FileMoveOne = new MovingFiles(sourcePath, targetPath);
        FileMoveOne.deleteFilesMethod();
        FileMoveOne.copyFilesMethod();

    }
}
```

What I understand once I run the below it would look every 10 seconds if there is a new file and then trigger the OnChange method, am I right?

```
public class HeartBeat
{
    private readonly Timer _timer;

    public HeartBeat()
    {
        _timer = new Timer(10000)
        {
            AutoReset = true
        };
        _timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
    }

    private void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //StringBuilder loggingLine = new StringBuilder();
        /* Every 30 seconds it will write to the file */
        string[] lines = new string[] {DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": Heartbeat is active. Service is monitoring SS and DS"};
        //lines[1] = DateTime.Now.ToString() + " About to check if new files are placed on server";

            //loggingLine.Append(lines[i]);
            File.AppendAllLines(@"C:\Users\RLEBEDEVS\Desktop\Monitor\Monitor1\HeartBeat.log", lines);
        //File.AppendAllLines(@"C:\Users\RLEBEDEVS\Desktop\Monitor\Monitor1\HeartBeat.log", lines);
        FileMonitor versioOne = new FileMonitor(@"C:\Users\RLEBEDEVS\Desktop\Monitor\Monitor1", @"C:\Users\RLEBEDEVS\Desktop\Monitor\Monitor2");
        versioOne.watch();
    }

    public void Start ()
    {
        _timer.Start();
    }

    public void Stop ()
    {
        _timer.Stop();
    }
}
```

The issue I am having is inconsistency.

1. It should copy the files to the folder Monitor2 once a new folder is created, but it is not doing that on the first creation. It does delete and copy the files on the second time once create a folder in monitor1 folder.
2. On every second time it is trying to copy  the files it crashes with the below error which I am not familiar with:

   > Topshelf.Hosts.ConsoleRunHost Critical: 0 : The service threw an unhandled exception, System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\RLEBEDEVS\Desktop\Monitor\Monitor2\System.Net.Sockets.dll' is denied.
   >   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   >   at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)
   >   at System.IO.File.Delete(String path)
   >   at UpgradeServices.MovingFiles.deleteFilesMethod() in C:\Users\RLEBEDEVS\Desktop\C#\Service\UpgradeServices\MovingFIles.cs:line 48
   >   at UpgradeServices.FileMonitor.OnChanged(Object source, FileSystemEventArgs e) in C:\Users\RLEBEDEVS\Desktop\C#\Service\UpgradeServices\FileMonitor.cs:line 43
   >   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.OnCreated(FileSystemEventArgs e)
   >   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.NotifyFileSystemEventArgs(Int32 action, String name)
   >   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.CompletionStatusChanged(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* overlappedPointer)
   >   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
   >
   > Topshelf.Hosts.ConsoleRunHost Information: 0 : Stopping the UpgradeServices service
   >   Topshelf.Hosts.ConsoleRunHost Information: 0 : The UpgradeServices service has stopped.
   >
   > The program '[497452] UpgradeServices.exe' has exited with code 1067 (0x42b).

Line 48 is this one, though it performed the tasks previously fine (on the first go).

```
System.IO.File.Delete(deleteString);
```

I see that the issue is with the way I am raising the event. Does anybody know what should I change in order to achieve the desired result which is when the service is started on every new folder created in the destiny it would perform the two methods moving and deleting files? The folder will always have only new folders created.

Regards,

Comment: Is your program attempting to delete `System.Net.Sockets.dll`? Is it supposed to be doing that?

Comment: Are you trying to update your own service by first deleting the files in your executable's directory? That won't work. You cannot delete or overwrite the files the application is currently executing. There are different ways to do this, but it can't be done from the application being updated itself.

Comment: The files it is deleting the folder from is not where the service is located. The files there are for a different service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that in your heartbeat you starting new `FileMonitor` every 10 seconds, so after 20 seconds you will have 2 `FileMonitor`'s watching and moving(deleting) the same files at the time. Just start `FileMonitor` once using [hosted service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) for example. Or remove the timer handler part in your `HeartBeat` class and just create `FileMonitor` in constructor:

```
public HeartBeat()
{
    FileMonitor versioOne = new 
    FileMonitor(@"C:\Users\RLEBEDEVS\Desktop\Monitor\Monitor1", @"C:\Users\RLEBEDEVS\Desktop\Monitor\Monitor2");
    versioOne.watch(); 
   // may be save it to instance field so it does not get garbage collected.
   // Not sure how FileSystemWatcher behaves with subscription, 
   // it should prevent the "versionOne" from being collected via subscription.
}
```

Comment: This actually looks to be working very well. Two questions. Do I need the timer in order to have this to monitor the folder? I will do some additional testing on the first, once I move the FileMonitor and versionOne.watch to the constrictor it did work and did not crash.

Comment: @RaitisLebedevs, no, you don't, [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netcore-3.1) listens to changes in specified directory continuously until  it is disposed.